# Android: ViewPager needed?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to make a layout where you can swipe right and left to change the view content. However, I don't need to change the layout, I just need to change the texts in the TextViews and some visibility changes when swiping right or left. Do I need a ViewPager for that? And if yes, could you give me a link to some example.
I'm just a bit lost, I don't know what to google (and that's about the only problem google can't help you with:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [TextSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextSwitcher.html) or even a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) if you just want to change the text and you can check gestures out for the swipe action, if you decided to use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) you can check the example provided above, or search google for more examples I am sure you will find lots.